# Faster way to calculate pairwise interaction between elements in list?

Tags: python, performance, loops, iteration

I'm trying to find a more efficient way of looping over a list of lists, calculating pairwise interactions between all elements in each sublist. In my code is an array of numbers, corresponding to pairwise interactions between all objects in the simulation. I've tried using itertools.combinations, but can't seem to get the results I want, probably through lack of understanding of how itertools works.

The current method of multiple nested loops means the code takes a long time to run, and itertools.combinations doesn't give the results I am expecting.

My current method of looping is:

```
for i in droplets:
    for a in i:
    species_check = []
        for b in i:
          if b!=a >>> get pairwise interaction from matrix
```

I've also tried:

```
for i in droplets
    for a in i:
        for a,b in itertools.combinations(i,2):
            >>> get pairwise interactions
```

I expected the second one to iterate over each sublist (for a in i) and give every pairwise interaction (for a,b in itertools.combinations). This however, just gives every possible pairwise combination in the droplet, repeated x times, where x is the number of objects in the sublist

I expect for example, for the sublist [a,b,c,d] to loop over the sublist and get:

```
     a,b
     a,c
     a,d
```

in the first iteration, then:

```
     b,a
     b,c
     b,d
```

in the second, and so on

Comment: Might be that I don't know the term, but what do you mean by "interaction"/"pairwise interaction"?

Comment: If you describe an example input with an expected output, things might become a bit clearer.

Comment: What do your lists contain? If you work with nummeric data, it might be good to check packages like `numpy` or `pandas`

Comment: @Tobb, sorry I should've been clearer. I should've stated that the items in the list are objects, that interact with all other objects in their respective sublist, in that, they either stop an object from growing, do not interact at all, or produce growth in an object. These are all contained in an array. The simplest example of this would be three items in a sublist. That means, for every item, there are two interactions, one from each of the other items. What I basically want to do, is find a way to collect and evaluate these matrix values, for every item in a sublist. Thank you!

Comment: @MrFuppes Each sublist contains objects. I've read briefly about pandas, but will take a second look. Thank you!